# Compare two folders and list differences in third folder in Windows

Tags: cmd, robocopy

I have 3 folders, /Incoming, /Processed and /Temp. The incoming folder is updated with new files hourly and currently has 120k+ individual .zip files in it. Every hour these files are copied to the processed folder. where they are unzipped and the records are inserted into a SQL table. The table is Dropped and Recreated every hour and all files are re-imported. This process is starting to take a long time.

All the file transfers are currently being done in a cmd batch file, using robocopy /MIR and a SQL .dtsx file for importing.

I am trying to find a method to compare the incoming folder with the processed folder before new files are copied every hour, and copy the differences to the temp folder so only they are added to SQL instead of dropping and recreating every hour.

Any help would be awesome as I have spent hours on this single issue with no luck.

Comment: Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service! Please share what you have tried so far and tell us where you are stuck! Read the [tour] and learn how to use this site!

Comment: Apologies aschipfl. I am a beginner and wasn't sure where I went wrong. I should have made that clearer. I have the solution in Powershell and will make it available for anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will compare two folders (e.g. Incoming and Processed) and copy the new files in the first folder (Incoming) to the third folder (Temp) for processing.

```
$Folder1 = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "C:\Incoming") 
$Folder2 = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "C:\Processed") 
(Diff $Folder1 $Folder2 | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}).InputObject | 
ForEach-Object { 
   $ItemName1 = $_; 
   $ItemName2 = "C:\Temp\" + $ItemName1; 
   Copy-Item $ItemName2 -Destination "C:\Temp" -Force 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use fc command 
ex : fc srcfile destfile >logfile

or use ROBOCOPY